# Reqular Expression for getting sub-string, if not exist get other

Tags: php, regex

I have a reqular expression for getting sub-string from a string, if a particular string doesn't exist then try to get another sub-string.

Reqular expression i am trying is this:

```
\@\s*\((.*?)\)|\((.*?)\)
```

But this does not work, and always get the second option sub-string instead of the first option.

Example string is

> some text (2nd Sub-string) @  (First sub-string)

And it give me this result:

```
Array
(
   [0] =>  (2nd Sub-string)
   [1] => 
   [2] => 2nd Sub-string
)
```

Comment: I don't see why this won't work... for me it returns `(First sub-string)` for the first capturing group.

Comment: HI Basti: i am testing at this... http://www.phpliveregex.com

Comment: Then using `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` will give you both capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply get both strings (for which your regexp works correctly) and check their existence programmatically? Something like:

```
$num = preg_match_all(
    "/\@\s*\((.*?)\)|\((.*?)\)/", 
    "some text (2nd Sub-string) @ (First sub-string)", 
    $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER
    );
var_dump($num, $matches);
if($num < 2)
    {
    // no second match, read first
    }
if(!array_key_exists(2, $matches[1]))
    {
    // another way to put it
    }
```

HTH.

Comment: It still doesn't give me anything NULL result.

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you actually call `preg_match_all` and how you access the results?

Comment: Yes, you are right preg_match_all get both... but why its not working for retrieving one at a time..